# Fixed text in TextBox

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

How can I dynamically add fixed text to a TextBox? By "fixed text", I mean text which can't be deleted by the user's input.

For example, the path in CMD:

```
C:\Program Files>cd ..
C:\>
```

Comment: So you want fixed text in a textbox where the user may append to it?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you want an editable textbox, that has some fixed text at the start of it that the user cannot edit.  If so then this seems to work - it's based on the standard textbox style as extracted in Blend...

You need to have the following namespace declaration in your xaml root:

```
     xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
```

Then use this template:

```
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
        <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="Bd" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderMouseOver="{TemplateBinding IsMouseOver}" RenderFocused="{TemplateBinding IsKeyboardFocusWithin}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">This is fixed:</TextBlock>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
          </StackPanel>
    </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

If you were to wrap this in a custom control or user control, you could programmatically set the fixed text through a custom property.

Answer (score 0):

TextBox IsReadOnly = true when you populate the text dynamically? if you use MVVM bind IsReadOnly to a property in your ViewModel, when that ViewModel populates the text

Answer (score 0):

You can use a textblock instead.
If You have to use a textbox, you can do it Read Only changing the IsReadOnly property to "True"

Answer (score -2):

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1.SelectionStart < LengthOfFixedString)
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
}
```

Comment: That has a number of drawbacks: it doesn't stop cut/delete using the mouse, and if the user cursors into the fixed text they won't be able to cursor back out again.